# Common configuration in entity framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, configuration

I have a couple of entities, all inherits base entity with auditing and ID fields. In the configuration for each property I have absolutely same lines like:

```
this.HasKey(t0 => t0.Id)
  .Map(m => m.ToTable("templates"))
  .Property(x => x.Id)
  .HasColumnName("id")
  ...................
```

Is there way to move this code to some kind of "base configuration" to not to write it for each entity?

Answer (score 0):

All you'd need to do is to implement either Table-Per-Type or Table-Per-Hierarchy:

In Table-Per-Type your entities will be split into different tables, but all offshoot tables will have its PK be a FK to the base entity table.

In Table-Per-Hierarchy your entities will all be in one table, but EF will generate a discriminator to discern which object type the entity is actually a part of.

For a clearer example of this, check out the post [at this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393228/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Inheritance-Table-Per).

Comment: Thank you for feedback, I already override OnModelCreating of my context and added all required mappings/keys/relations. so I using TPT (TPH looks like nighmare). Actually, I want to reduce code repetitions and want to know how to move repetitive part to one place.